# Nested loop and XOR - Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nested-loops, xor

I am currently having an issue with my program that assembles fine but crashes when running. I think it might have to do with how I am using the `xor` instruction. I've only ever used `xor` as a key encryption, and I think I am using it wrong when doing a bit flip. I've tried moving things around in the innerloop to the outer with no changes to it crashing and I'm out of ideas. The point of this program is to have 100 people go and open 100 lockers. The first one will open all of them, the second one will then open/close every second locker and so on. We're supposed to set the Array to 101 so we could use the 1-100 instead of 0-99.

I am using Assembly x86 ASM, on Microsoft Visual Studios 2010.

Edit: I changed things around as suggested and it doesn't crash, but the output only has a few of the answers right. Only numbers that can be squared should be open. I fixed the code below to show what I have now

```
.data
Locker Byte 101 dup(0)
temp Dword 1
Students DWORD ?
.code
main Proc

   mov   ecx, SIZEOF Locker
   dec   ecx
   mov   eax, 0
OuterLoop:
   mov   Students, ecx; keeps counter for Outer
   mov   ecx, 100; The lockers
   inc   eax
   Call  WriteDec; to show which locker is opened/closed
   mov   esi, 0
InnerLoop:
   xor   Locker[esi+eax], 1
   add   esi, temp; goes to next locker

Loop InnerLoop

   mov   ecx, Students

   cmp   Locker[esi], 0
   jz    isClosed
   jnz   isOpen

isClosed:
   mWrite" closed."
   Call   Crlf
  jmp    Restart

isOpen:
   Mwrite" open."
   Call   Crlf
   jmp    Restart

Restart:

loop OuterLoop
ret
main ENDP
```

Comment: The xor seems okay, the problem is that `esi` goes out of bounds because it's never reset. Also I guess you wanted to `inc temp` instead of `inc esi` on the 3rd line from the bottom.

Comment: Still seems to crash. Changed `inc esi` to `inc temp` It seems to crash right when entering the inner loop.

Comment: You're using `Locker[esi]` even though `esi` was initialized with `OFFSET Locker`. And as @Jester pointed out, it doesn't seem like you're resetting `esi` before starting another iteration of the outer loop.